# ANTLR How to specify which listener (or lexer/parser) I want to be used based on input on my multi-grammar structure?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

**MainLangFile.g4**

```
grammar MainLangFile;

import Child1LangFile, Child2LangFile;

parse:
    A (child1 | child2) EOF
;

A: 'A';
B: 'B';
C: 'C';
```

**Child1LangFile.g4**

```
grammar Child1LangFile;

child1:
    CHILD1
;

CHILD1: 'CHILD1';
```

**Child2LangFile.g4**

```
grammar Child2LangFile;

child2:
    CHILD2
;

CHILD2: 'CHILD2';
```

**My Java application:**

```
public static class MyApp {

    public void execute(String query) {

        MainLangFileLexer lexer = new MainLangFileLexer(CharStreams.fromString(query));
        MainLangFileParser parser = new MainLangFileParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        MainLangFileParser.ParseContext parse = parser.parse();

        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        walker.walk(new Child1Listener(), parse);
        walker.walk(new Child2Listener(), parse);
    }

    static class Child1Listener extends MainLangFileBaseListener {

        @Override
        public void enterChild1(MainLangFileParser.Child1Context ctx) {
        }
    }


    static class Child2Listener extends MainLangFileBaseListener {

        @Override
        public void enterChild2(MainLangFileParser.Child2Context ctx) {
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to have a multi-grammar structure. The solution I've above works perfectly in the sense that each `ChildXListener` is properly invoked based on the query. It would be the same as just having a single listener and implementing both methods.

The issue begins where there is a `enterCommon()` method invoked, it is invoked for both listeners even though I "forked" the language and went only on one specific direction.

I need a clever way of selecting which listener should be used by `ParseTreeWalker`.

Also, I'd rather have each listener, extending their respective grammars, i.e.: `Child1Listener` should extends `Child1LangFileBaseListener`, by doing so I have a clear scope of what methods I can safely override as only `Child1LangFile.g4` rules will be available.

I couldn't figure out a way of doing this without initializing `Child1Lexer`, `Child1Parser` and parsing everything again, either way, this brings me back to the previous issue, how do I know which lexer/parser to use?

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tell up front which parser rule(s) are going to be invoked for a given input source.

Since a visitor will not cause the entire parse tree to be visited (you determine that by overriding only the method you wish to visit), you could start off by writing a visitor that can be used up until the rule that contains the `(child1 | child2)` and inside that `visit...` method, invoke the specific listener.

That could look something like this:

```java
class MainVisitor extends MainLangFileBaseVisitor<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object visitParse(MainLangFileParser.ParseContext ctx) {

        if (ctx.child1() != null) {
            ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new Child1Listener(), ctx);
        }
        else {
            ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new Child2Listener(), ctx);
        }

        return null;
    }
}

class Child1Listener extends Child1LangFileBaseListener {
    // ...
}

class Child2Listener extends Child2LangFileBaseListener {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Cool. This is the same solution I ended up with. The only "gotcha" is that you also need to instantiate Child1Lexer, Child1Parser, parse it and only then you can invoke ParseTreeWalker with Child1Listener. This is necessary because of `enterRule()` in `MainLangFileParser` having `if (listener instanceof MainListener) ((MainListener)listener).enterParse(this);`